# Multiple JOINs issue in TSQL

Tags: sql, join, northwind

Northwind DB
Customers and Suppliers tables both have Country column (there is no Country table in the DB, so the Country field is not a FK).

Argentina has no suppliers, but 3 customers.

Task: "Produce a full list of countries (derived from Customers and Suppliers tables) with total number of customers and suppliers for every country. In case a country has no (NULL) customers or suppliers, put 0 (zero)".

Solution:

```
USE Northwind
GO

WITH
CountryList AS
(SELECT Country FROM Customers UNION SELECT Country FROM Suppliers),
SupplierCountry AS
(SELECT Country, TotalSuppliers=COUNT(*) FROM Suppliers GROUP BY Country),
CustomerCountry AS
(SELECT Country, TotalCustomers=COUNT(*) FROM Customers GROUP BY Country)

SELECT cl.Country, ISNULL(sc.TotalSuppliers,0) C, ISNULL(cc.TotalCustomers,0) TotalCustomers
FROM CountryList cl LEFT JOIN SupplierCountry sc ON cl.Country=sc.Country
                    LEFT JOIN CustomerCountry cc ON sc.Country=cc.Country
```

The expected result for Argentina is:

```
Country TotalSuppliers TotalCustomers

Argentina 0 3
```

Instead, the result is:

```
Argentina 0 0
```

(same pattern for every other country with no suppliers but some customers)

As far as understand, the 1st LEFT JOIN produces an intermediate result "Argentina 0".
The 2nd LEFT JOIN should join this result with Argentina's customers count (3).

What do I miss?

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Shouldn't it be    `Left JOIN CustomerCountry cc ON cl.Country=cc.Country` ?

Comment: The result of the 1st left join has 3 columns. That is the left table of the 2nd left join. The result of the 2nd left join has 5 columns. You don't seem to know what left join does. PS Why aren't you just looking at what these joins produce? (Rhetorical.) `select * from ...`

Comment: @sgmoore
1. Thank you very much! Your fix did the job.
2. I was confused by this article which explicitly says that in multiple JOINs the following JOIN joins a table to the previous (intermediate) result set (not to the previous table):
https://blog.quest.com/an-overview-of-sql-join-types-with-examples/#:~:text=SQL%20joins%20with%20multiple%20tables

Comment: @MichaelShuv That may be true in their example but isn't always the case.  For example, with the Northwind database, if you start with the OrderDetails and join the Orders table to that, that if you want the customer details you need to use the intermediate results (Orders) but to get the product details you the need to join to the original table (OrderDetails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last join currently

`LEFT JOIN CustomerCountry cc ON sc.Country=cc.Country`

should actually be

`Left JOIN CustomerCountry cc ON cl.Country=cc.Country`

If there are any suppliers for a country, then sc.country is the same as cl.country (due to preceding join), but if there are no suppliers for a country, then sc.Country will be null.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand the logic now.